# How do I validate a JSON Schema schema, in Python?

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am programmatically generating a JSON-Schema schema.  I wish to ensure that the schema is valid.  Is there a schema I can validate my schema against?

Please note my use of schema twice in that sentence and the title.  I don't want to validate data against my schema, I want to validate my schema.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using [jsonschema](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema/0.7), you can validate a schema against the meta-schema.  The core meta-schema is [here](http://json-schema.org/), but jsonschema bundles it so downloading it is unnecessary.

```
from jsonschema import Draft3Validator
my_schema = json.loads(my_text_file) #or however else you end up with a dict of the schema
Draft3Validator.check_schema(my_schema)
```